# Do not receive a POST request

Tags: http, post, laravel-5

I have a website at the address `http://sakura-city.info`.

In that site I have a route:

```
Route::post('/yandex','GirlsController@reciverYandex');
```

Controller:

```
public function reciverYandex(Request $request){
    echo 'yandex';
    Storage::put('file.txt','Test');
}
```

I send post request address: `sakura-city.info/yandex`

But in `file.txt` there is no new text.

Path to file: `public/file.txt`

Has my site not received the request?

Comment: Can you also show us your form that is posting the request?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function reciverYandex(Request $request){
        $date= Carbon::now();
        File::append(base_path().'/public/file.txt', 'data2'.PHP_EOL);
        File::append(base_path().'/public/file.txt','oprration_id:'. $request['operation_id'].','.'datetime: '.$request['datetime'].','.$request['sha1_hash'].','.$request['currency'].',lable:'.$request['lable'].','.$date.PHP_EOL);
```